# Can all lan connected PCs to internet router get infected if only one does?

Tags: networking, router, ssh, security, lan

Can all lan conected PCs to internet router get infected if only one PC gets infected by malware (rat)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, most definitely.

It is absolutely possible for malware to spread through your LAN to your computer.

In fact, I’ve heard horror stories of malware that makes it past one person’s defenses to infect a single machine … and from that machine, move on to infect an entire small business’s network.

While most malware these days has to be “invited” in – by downloading and running an infected file, or opening an infected attachment – another, perhaps even older class of malware is still present: the network-based threat.

Network-based malware simply uses your machine’s network connection to probe for other machines on the network, and then attempts to exploit any network-based vulnerabilities on that machine. If successful, the malware can spread from machine to machine simply by using the network connection.